# How to watch for file changes in Loopback 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopback

I have the following:

```
nodemon server/server.js --watch common --watch serve
```

This doesn't work at all. Alright, maybe it's because `server/server.js` doesn't exist! So I tried the following:

```
nodemon index.js --watch common --watch serve
```

Still it didn't work. I also changed `common` with `src`. That didn't work either. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install package `tsc-watch` if you don't have it installed yet: `npm install -D tsc-watch`

You can add this line under your `"scripts"` tag in `package.json`:

```
"start:watch": "tsc-watch --target es2017 --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"node .\"",
```

And use `npm run start:watch` instead of `npm run start`.

It helps automatically detect any source-code changes and restart the server as well.

Reference: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2242#issuecomment-476866232

Comment: Also install `npm install -i tsc-watch`

Comment: Much love brother to you, this is the best, easier and efficient way I have found on the Internet about this

Answer (score 19):

*Hello from the LoopBack team :)*

LoopBack 4 applications use different project layout. They are written in TypeScript, store TypeScript sources in `src` and transpiled JavaScript files in `dist`. There are no `common` and `serve` (did you mean `server`?) directories to watch for changes.

It is not enough to watch for changes in your source code, you also need to recompile from TypeScript to JavaScript before restarting the app.

We are looking into the best way how to support automatic reload of LB4 applications in development, please subscribe to the discussion in [issue #2242](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2242).

A community user recommended the following nodemon config, it should be added to application's `package.json` file:

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": [
      "src"
    ],
    "ext": "ts",
    "exec": "npm start"
  }
```

Comment: Nodemon is not good, sometimes it throws this https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1247

Answer (score -1):

Install : npm install -D tsc-watch
In package.json into "scripts" tag

"start:watch": "tsc-watch --target es2017 --outDir ./dist --onSuccess "node ."",
And use npm run start: watch instead of npm run start.

Automatically compile source code and changes are shown into the browser.